# Lowering the water pressure in my bathtub spout

Tags: bathtub, spout

I have a small tankless water heater and the flow from my bathtub spout is too strong and the water will not get hot. How can I reduce the flow in just the bathtub spout?

Comment: You can add a flow restrictor to the tub pipe outlet, this won't work if you have a showerhead that uses the tub spout diverter valve.

Comment: your question makes no sense .... there is already a "flow restrictor" on your tub spout .... just don't open it fully

Comment: @jsotola - see the above comment about shower heads as to why. But actually if so, **fill the tub with the shower head** (ideally a wand hanging down). Perhaps half way in between a setting, so that the flow really sucks, or mostly shut off if it has that setting.

Comment: @Mazura, the "flow restrictor" I am talking about, is the valve that is used to turn the water on/off .... simply turn it on partially ....... that is why the question makes no sense, unless the OP has failed to provide all of the information  ..... either way, the question is actually unclear .... downvoting

Comment: .... oh. Yeah, use that one.... But some are full cold +/- full hot... ? (especially with a shower). With certain types of single knob valves  this can be a problem

Comment: .... the ones you don't lift, they just turn. You get a bunch of cold along side, or go full hot: draining the system.

Comment: They can't get a hot bath going. What information do you want from them? @jsotola

Comment: @JesseHanwit please give us an update .... please describe clearly what kind of control you have .... can you turn it to `hot` only and adjust the flow? .... is there any flow control at all?   .................. also, please add a picture of your heater .... include a view of inlet and outlet pipes

Comment: "How can I reduce the flow in *just* the bathtub spout." - I think it's safe to assume (the question we might as well answer anyway) there's a shower head involved considering the use of the word "just". And the worst type of designed valve ever (as I've mentioned). Please do update us though if you've found a solution, OP.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add an aereator (aka economizer) to your tub faucet: it will, about halve, the flow used at a reasonable price.

If your water heater is smaller than 24 kW you should get a bigger one. (24kW allows 10L/min flow @30K temperature's jump) that is pretty low flow and not-very-hot water, if you live in hot regions it may be good (cold water hotter than 15°)

Comment: I haven't taken one off in a while. You can *just* put an aerator in there?

Comment: It depends, some faucets come already equiped with an aereator others come with a simple diffuser. If possible post a photo of the spigot, usually those are scewed in the outlet. these: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71Xwf9az6gL._SL1500_.jpg are for spigot and these for the handset pipe: https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/51zh0jzf7JL.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Get a shut off for the shower head (or one that shuts off) and try jsotola's idea: just don't open the tub spout fully. A shower head is a lot easier to take off than a tub spout (anything but that - you'd have to, to put an aerator).